EF Core : how to make sure we get up to date data from a DbSet
I'm pretty new to EF Core and I'm a facing an issue where I get some entities that do not seem to exist in my database anymore.
Here is how I proceed:
var myEntity = _context.MyDbSet.Where(m => m.ResourceType == "aResourceType").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (myEntity != null)
{
    _context.MyDbSet.Remove(myEntity);
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

which causes this error:

The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Reading the documentation, I saw that the LINQ request generated to retrieve the data might not return up-to-date data.
I think this issue happens because the data was deleted elsewhere and I'm not able to see those changes.
I've seen some topics about reloading the dbContext, but is there another option to make sure I get current data?
I tried
_context.Entry(_context.MyDbSet).Reload();

but since _context.MyDbSet is not an entity, this generates an error

The entity type 'InternalDbSet' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.


need to await those async calls
